# Having a "flash" of extra content using jquery tabs in Wordpress site sidebar

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fouc

I have created a wordpress website that is using a jquery navigation tab in the sidebar. It's a really cool addition, but my client is complaining that when the page loads, you see a partial list item load to the right of all 3 tabs. I have actually looked and it does it in IE and Firefox so far. I don't understand the technology just yet, but has anyone experienced this "flash" using jquery functions? [Here's an example page.](http://thurstonchamber.com/?page_id=546)

Comment: Thanks for the tag Ken. Didn't realize that was an actual term :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that by pushing your nav tabs apart a little more:

```
//in glide.css
.tabnav li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin-right: 10px; /* my alteration */
    text-align: center; 
}
```

By messing with that margin-right you should be able to solve your problem.  Otherwise try playing with it using Firebug.

Comment: Wow, that actually worked! I remember a while back messing with the margins in that style sheet, but I didn't realize what it had done. Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction :)